# Stored Procedure - Clear columns except those given

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way, using dynamic SQL, to clear all columns in a given table, except those passed in?

Example - I have a table that will have columns added in the future, but it always has a group of columns that I don't want to delete.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_clearTable](

@columnExclusionList varchar(500),
@tableName varchar(100)
)

AS
BEGIN

in @tableName, clear all columns except those in @columnExclusionList

go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with a couple of caveats.

1. your particular brand of SQL (you don't say whether its ms sql, oracle, sqlite, etc) must implement something like information_schema, and
2. either primary keys have to be among the excluded columns, or you can't have a primary key (almost always a disastrous decision).

That said:

```
Declare @columns varchar(max);
Set @columns='';
Select @columns = @columns + column_name +','
From information_schema.columns
Where table_name = @tablename;
```

Gives a list of comma separated values in T-SQL (SQL Server).  How you would deal with the exclusion list depends upon what version and product. In SQL Server 2008 you could use a table valued parameter, or you could use string splitting to put the values into a temptable/variable.

I don't know your design, but I would suggest thinking about it carefully as this is definitely unusual - its likely that this is not the approach that you should be taking to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve,  but it can be done.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: marc - it's SQL Server 2008. This got me headed in the right direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @marc_s: sorry about that, I do know about and try to make everything pretty, but for some reason it doesn't always work from my iPad, and I didn't have time to fix it by hand.